# How do I write a cookie inside a static webmethod

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, static-methods

I'm using John Culviner's [jquery.filedownload](http://johnculviner.com/post/2012/03/22/Ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads-with-jQuery-File-Download.aspx)  plugin.

For that to work I need to write a cookie. How do I write a cookie from within a static webmethod? As Page. Response is an instance field I cannot access it from a static method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `HttpContext.Current` property in your `WebMethod`.

Answer (score 7):

```
var myCookie = new HttpCookie("CookieName");
myCookie["key"] = "val";

HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Get("CookieName");
```

Answer (score 1):

use the ff: code:

```
HttpCookie objHTTPCk = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Get("Cookie name");
```